# About Dependency Conflict Error when Integrating Firestore and BigQuery in Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I am currently developing an Android app using Kotlin in Android Studio. In the backend, I am using Firestore, and I have implemented the "Stream Firestore to BigQuery" extension, which allows for complex queries using SQL language. Thanks to this extension, data is automatically mirrored and migrated to BigQuery when I upload data to Firestore.

However, when I added the BigQuery client API to my Android Studio's Build.gradle in order to directly retrieve data from BigQuery using SQL queries, I encountered the following error:

I am seeking guidance on how to resolve this dependency conflict error and successfully integrate Firestore and BigQuery in my Android Studio project. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

build.gradle(Project)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.21"
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.7.1"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.1.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.1.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.21' apply false
    id 'com.google.devtools.ksp' version "1.9.0-1.0.11" apply false
}

tasks.register('clean', Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle(Module:app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'com.google.devtools.ksp'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
}

android {
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "jp.ac.shinshu.babatomohiro.sharingtravel"
        minSdk 27
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_18
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_18
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '18'
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled true
    }

    namespace 'jp.ac.shinshu.babatomohiro.sharingtravel'
}

dependencies {


    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'

    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0"

    //LiveData and ViewModel dependency
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1'

    //Navigation dependency
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.7.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.7.1'


    //Firebase dependency
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.2.2')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx:21.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx:22.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx:24.7.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx:20.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-ktx:23.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx:21.3.0'


    implementation 'com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:4.3.0'

    //Glide dependency
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.16.0'

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1'


    implementation 'com.github.krokyze:ucropnedit:2.2.8'

    implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:3.0.1'

    implementation 'com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.1.22'
    implementation 'com.iceteck.silicompressorr:silicompressor:2.2.4'

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.7.3"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.7.3"


    implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-core:1.2.3'
    implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.2.3'
    implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.2.3'
    implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-video:1.2.3'
    implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-view:1.2.3'
    implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-extensions:1.2.3'

    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.19.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.19.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:2.19.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.19.1'

    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:32.1.2-jre'

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.5.2"
    ksp "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.2"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.5.2"

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:3.2.0'

    implementation 'com.github.MikeOrtiz:TouchImageView:3.2.1'

    implementation 'io.github.nikartm:image-support:2.0.0'

    implementation 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.13.19'

    implementation 'com.github.shuhart:stepview:1.5.1'

    implementation 'me.relex:circleindicator:2.1.6'

    implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:20.28.3'


    //Bigquery API
    implementation platform('com.google.cloud:libraries-bom:26.22.0')
    implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-bigquery'


    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

Build Output

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class com.google.api.Advice found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.23.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.23.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     
     Duplicate class com.google.api.MonitoredResourceProto found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.23.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.23.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.api.Monitoring found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.23.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.23.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.api.Monitoring$1 found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.23.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.23.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.api.Monitoring$Builder found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.23.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.23.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.DescriptorProtos$ExtensionRangeOptionsOrBuilder found in modules protobuf-java-3.23.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.23.2) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.DescriptorProtos$FieldDescriptorProto found in modules protobuf-java-3.23.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.23.2) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.DescriptorProtos$FieldDescriptorProto$Builder found in modules protobuf-java-3.23.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.23.2) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.DescriptorProtos$FieldDescriptorProto$Label found in modules protobuf-java-3.23.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.23.2) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)

                                  ................ omitted.....................

 Duplicate class com.google.type.TimeZone$1 found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.23.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.23.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.type.TimeZone$Builder found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.23.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.23.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.type.TimeZoneOrBuilder found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.23.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.23.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     
     Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there **is** a Google Cloud SDK to use [BigQuery in Java](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java), that SDK is meant to use in server-side JVM environments and **not** in client-side Android code. There is (as far as I know) no Google-supported SDK for accessing BigQuery directly from within your Android code, as that'd require the Android user to have a level of access to your Google Cloud project that is not recommended.

---

The normal way to use BigQuery in an Android project would be to:

1. Implement BigQuery either on a server you already have or on something like Cloud Run or Cloud Functions.
2. Ensure the custom code is callable with a custom API endpoint.
3. Then call that from within your Android code.

Now the code you write in step 1 can do all the sensitive operations with the server-side BigQuery API. The code in step 2 can ensure it only allows calls from authorized users, in whatever that means for your app and use-case. And in step 3 you can call the API from Android, process the results, and display them to the user.

This traditional 3-tier model of developing apps is necessary here since BigQuery doesn't have SDKs for direct client-side access, such as you're used to from native Firebase products.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I was able to resolve the issue by installing @google-cloud/bigquery in my Firebase function, using the BigQuery API to retrieve data from BigQuery, and then calling functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {}) from my local Android Studio to migrate the data locally. I'm still a beginner in programming, so this was really helpful for me.

Comment: Great to hear you got it working.  --- Honestly, if you got all of those steps working, you're rapidly on your way to not being a beginner anymore. :)